# How can we call SetExpireAfterSeconds in go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options/indexoptions.go?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mongo-go

How can we call SetExpireAfterSeconds in go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options/indexoptions.go ?

I need to auto delete document with specific time. How do we achieve this with golang ? How do we use  {expireAfterSeconds: 60} in golang with mongo-driver client library ?

Answer (score 1):

The [`options.IndexOptions`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.3/mongo/options#IndexOptions) type has an `ExpireAfterSeconds` fields for this purpose. Use the [`options.Index()`](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.4.3/mongo/options#Index) builder to easily set it when creating the index:

```
indexName, err := coll.Indexes().CreateOne(
    context.Background(),
    mongo.IndexModel{
        Keys:    bson.D{{Key: "fieldName", Value: 1}},
        Options: options.Index().SetExpireAfterSeconds(60),
    },
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried with above snippet , collection created successfully and indexed also created but collection is not getting delete after specified time.Do we need to apply any other condition  ?

Comment: @harry_cool You have to insert documents where `fieldName` is initialize to the current time of insertion (`time.Now()`).